# Turning ctypes.POINTER(instance) into an actual instance?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I have the following `ctypes` function which takes in a filename and return a pointer to an Image instance:

```
class Image(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = (
      ('image_info', ImageInfo),
      ('type', ctypes.c_int),
      ('format', ctypes.POINTER(Format) ),
  )
my_image_open = _lib.my_image_open
my_image_open.argtypes = [ ctypes.c_char_p ]
my_image_open.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Image)
```

I'd like to provide some syntactic sugar and wrap `my_image_open` within the Image constructor. However I cannot simply bind the returned pointer to `self`:

```
class Image(ctypes.Structure):
  def __init__( self, filename ):
    img = my_image_open( filename )
    self = img[0] # does not work, since self is local !
```

Does it make sense to do something like the above, or should I simply stay with a free-standing function returning an instance:

```
c_image_open = _lib.my_image_open
c_image_open.argtypes = [ ctypes.c_char_p ]
c_image_open.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Image)
# syntactic sugar:
def my_image_open( filename ):
  img = c_image_open( filename )
  return img[0]
```

Comment: It's plural `argtypes`, not `argtype`. No, it makes no sense to call a constructor function in the `__init__` initializer. You'd have to use `__new__`, but I don't recommend it. Instead, add an alternate constructor as an `Image.open`  `classmethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up following @eryksun suggestion:

```
class Image(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = (
      ('image_info', ImageInfo),
      ('type', ctypes.c_int),
      ('format', ctypes.POINTER(Format) ),
  )
  @classmethod
  def open(cls,filename):
    img = my_image_open( filename )
    if img: return img[0]
    return None
```